# Why aren't any of my css styles being applied to any of the items in my navigation area?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place my 3 `list items` to the left, and my `button` to the right. I've checked it over a bunch of times, but I can't find my mistake. Here's the code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #24252A;
}

li,
a,
button {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  Color: #edf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  Color: #edf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav_links">
        <li><a href="about.html">About</li>
                <li><a href="packages.html">Packages</li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <a class="cta" href="quote.html"><button>Get A Quote</button></a>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Two things. Your HTML is invalid as you forgot to close your links. Then in your CSS `Color` needs to be `color`

Comment: Also try deleting `</html>` at the very end. Check your browser console for any error messages as well.

Comment: @j08691 Actually according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link), `link` tag does not need to get closed.

Comment: @SMAKSS I'm going by the W3 validator, https://validator.w3.org/ and I'm talking about anchors `<a>`, not `<link>` elements

Comment: @j08691 Well, that's my bad I thought you are talking about `<link>` tags. Either way `<link>` tag does not need to get closed in w3 validator as well. 

Comment: Turns out I'm actually just a dumbass. I had a style sheet from a previous project open instead of the one for the project I was working on. They had the same name so I didn't really think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I must say that you are missing some `</a>` in the posted code. Make sure you fix them. You can use `justify-content: space-between;` to make them appear on left and right. I have created a code snipped that may be helpful. Please check this.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

header{
  background-color:tomato;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
  
  height:100px;
}

nav ul{
  list-style:none;
  display:flex;
}

nav ul li{
  margin-right:10px;
}

nav ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav_links">
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="packages.html">Packages</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a class="cta" href="quote.html"><button>Get A Quote</button></a>
  </header>
```